# Vue.js how to get key (left side value) from Json property.

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an object that looks like:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Customer",
  "parks": {
    "1": "Park a",
    "23": "Park b",
    "7": "Park c",
    "83": "Park d"
  },
  "users": {
    "11": "user@customer.com"
  }
}
```

The value on the left side in `parks` and `users` is not an index, but the actual `id` of the Park. How can I access this value in Javascript?

Currently I use Vue.Js, so I'm binding the value like this to a component:

```
<park-component v-for="park in customer.parks"
                            v-bind:prop="park"
                            v-bind:key="park.id">
</park-component>
```

This however, only binds the park value on the right side, i.e the name "park a". I need to be able to access the left side as well. If not possible through Vue in the html, can it be done in the script? i.e if I have:

`"23": "park b"`

How can I get `23` ?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

## Solution

You can iterate through objects using the `v-for` directive and get the key.

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="(value, key) in object">{{ key }}: {{ value }} </li>
</ul>
```

## Example

```js
new Vue({
  template: `
    <ul>
      <li v-for="(value, key) in object">{{ key }}: {{ value }} </li>
    </ul>
  `,
  
  data: () => {
    return {
      object: {
        key1: 'value1',
        key2: 'value2',
        key3: 'value3',
      },
    };
  },
}).$mount('#root');
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.3/vue.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

## Further reading

- [Vue documentation for list rendering with objects](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-an-Object)

Answer (score 2):

you first get the keys with: `Object.keys` and then loop it :)

I've included example how to access the values!

```js
var test = {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Customer",
  "parks": {
    "1": "Park a",
    "23": "Park b",
    "7": "Park c",
    "83": "Park d"
  },
  "users": {
    "11": "user@customer.com"
  }
};

var keys = Object.keys( test.parks );

for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
  console.log( test.parks[ keys[ i ] ] )
}
```

Comment: Although this works, it's slower and more complex than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is no element as `id` in `park`, use `index` like this

```
<park-component v-for="(park,index) in customer.parks"
                        v-bind:prop="park"
                        v-bind:key="index">
</park-component>
```

```js
var parkComponent = Vue.extend({
    template: "<div>Key : {{park_key}}, Prop : {{prop}}</div>",
    props: ['prop','park_key']
});
var app = new Vue({
    el: "#vue-instance",
    data: {
      customer:{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Customer",
        "parks": {
          "1": "Park a",
          "23": "Park b",
          "7": "Park c",
          "83": "Park d"
        },
        "users": {
          "11": "user@customer.com"
        }
      }
    },
    mounted() {
    },
    components: {
        parkComponent,
    },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.1/vue.js"></script>
<div id="vue-instance">
    <park-component v-for="(park,index) in customer.parks"
                            v-bind:prop="park"
                            v-bind:park_key="index">
</park-component>
</div>
```

**Note** : `key` will not work here `v-bind:key` as `key` is reserved